# JFace TableViewer shows two tooltips - custom and default

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I got a strange situation here where I need help.

I create a fairly simple JFace Table using a `TableViewer`. When you do nothing more, you can see the following behavior: when a cell's text is too large, a tooltip showing the complete text will appear after a short wait. That's normal behavior and I guess that the native controls draw these tooltips.

Now I added my own custom tooltips, using

```
ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor( tableViewer, ToolTip.NO_RECREATE );
```

And delivering a (different) text using `getToolTipText()` method of a label provider.

That works - almost. I got one problem: sometimes (not all the times!) first, the native tooltip appears and shortly thereafter my custom tooltip is drawn on top of it, like shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing two tooltips]

I have no idea how to effectively disable the native tooltips each cell wants to draw. It's ugly as hell the way it is...

Any clues for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can effectively disable the native table tooltip like this:

```
viewer.getTable().setToolTipText("");
```

See also...

- [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38100976/472992) from [Rüdiger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986905/r%C3%BCdiger-herrmann), adding some important hints and details missing in my answer
- this Eclipse Bug
  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218471
- and this Eclipse code snippet
  http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet125.java

for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to [@Jörg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472992/j%c3%b6rg) answer:

After setting the table's tool tip to the empty string, I still saw two tooltips occasionally with a multi-column table where some columns had tooltips and some had not.

The reason therefore was, that the `CellLabelProvider`s for columns without tooltips returned `null` from their `getToolTipText()` methods (the default) and `false` from their `useNativeToolTip()` (also the default). This, in turn, caused the table's tooltip to be reset to `null`. (see  line 174 in [ColumnViewerToolTipSupport](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/bundles/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.java)).

My first attempt was to let the label providers return an empty string from `getToolTipText()`. Though this fixed the duplicate tooltip problem, an empty custom tooltip was now shown (sigh). But letting `useNativeToolTip()` return true finally solved the problem.

Well, almost, if the mouse pointer is moved from a column without tooltip to a column with a tooltip, the tooltip is not shown. See this post for a workaround: [Native tooltips on JFace TableViewer not working flawlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105913/native-tooltips-on-jface-tableviewer-not-working-flawlessly/38105914#38105914)

If, for whatever reason, non-native tooltips are required, make sure to return true for `useNativeToolTip()` when `getToolTipText()` returns an empty string.

The notes taken here apply to Windows 7, other platforms may behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure from your screen shot, but I don't think that what you're seeing is actually two tool tips.

You *are* seeing one tool tip (your custom one).

The *other* "popup" you're seeing is the "this table cell isn't wide enough to display its full contents, so we're going to show you the full-blown text that we would be displaying *if we did have enough room to show it all*" feature of the table itself.

I'd offer up the notion that this is actually the desired behavior.  Allowing the user to continue to "peek" at the full contents of the cell, while also providing your custom tool tip (which I'm sure conveys additional/different info than the cell text itself), gives the user everything they might want.

If the overlap bothers you (and I agree that it's unpleasant), you could scoot your custom tool tip out of the way a bit by overriding `CellLabelProvider.getToolTipShift()`.

If you want to disable the "cell too narrow" helper-popup, I'm afraid I don't have any advice for you; I poked around for a while but couldn't figure out how to suppress it.  It may not even be possible to do so.

Comment: You are right that this "popup" shows the full text when the column is too small. But on the other hand: it does not happen everytime, only for the very first mouse over in the table and never ever again. Some of my columns show additional (other) text, but in others I want to display the complete text in my custom popup. What I really need is to know how to effectively disable this default behavior. It is not okay to overlay them - and it wouldn't help to shift my tooltip, it still looks ugly. Am I the first one to notice?