# jface tableviewer tooltip text cut

Tags: tooltip, jface, tableviewer

I am using the jface tableviewer in an eclipse rcp application to display some values.

Therefore I have written the following snipped ...

```
    tableviewer = new TableViewer(container, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    tableviewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

    ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(tableviewer, ToolTip.RECREATE);

    final Table table = tableviewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(tableviewer, SWT.NONE);
    column.getColumn().setText("col1");
    column.getColumn().setResizable(true);
    column.setLabelProvider(new ConfigLabelProvider("col1"));
```

And here here ConfigLabelProvider definition

```
private class ConfigLabelProvider extends StyledCellLabelProvider {

    private String property;

    public ConfigLabelProvider(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {

        GenericConfigInterfaceEntity config = (GenericConfigInterfaceEntity) cell.getElement();

        switch (property) {
        case "col1":
            cell.setText(AppHelper.preventNull("col1Text col1Text col1Text col1Text col1Text"));
            break;
        case ...
        }

        super.update(cell);

    }

}
```

Now my problem is if the column is too small, the default tooltip is displayed trying to show the full cell text value.

BUT I get a tooltip box that is large enough for the whole text but the text isn't shown outside the cell rectange.

[image]

If I extend the ConfigLabelProvider from CellLabelProvider the Tooltip is showing up like expected ...

[image]

But I need the paint method of the StyledCellLabelProvider.

Any ideas?

---

### Edit 1

I have written a small Java Example Project using SWT and JFACE, because my problems still remain.

My goal is to have an table with a cell-Background without the mousehover (because its looking ugly together) and a custom tooltip.

Here's my TestTable implementation

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.TestModel;

import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewerToolTipSupport;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;

public class TestTable extends Dialog {

    private TableViewer tableviewer;
    private List<TestModel> entities;

    protected TestTable(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {

        super.create();

        loadData();

    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

        GridData dataLayout;

        Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        dataLayout = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
        dataLayout.heightHint = 150;
        dataLayout.widthHint = 500;

        Composite wrapper = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
        wrapper.setLayoutData(dataLayout);
        wrapper.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        tableviewer = new TableViewer(wrapper, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
        tableviewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

        ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(tableviewer);

        final Table table = tableviewer.getTable();
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);

        createColumns(wrapper);

        return area;

    }

    private void createColumns(Composite wrapper) {

        TableViewerColumn firstnameColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableviewer, SWT.NONE);
        firstnameColumn.getColumn().setText("Vorname");
        firstnameColumn.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider(StyledCellLabelProvider.COLORS_ON_SELECTION) {

            @Override
            public void initialize(ColumnViewer viewer, ViewerColumn column) {
                super.initialize(viewer, column);
                this.setOwnerDrawEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                TestModel model = (TestModel) cell.getElement();
                cell.setText(model.getFirstname());
                cell.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
            }

            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(Object element) {
                TestModel model = (TestModel) element;
                return "USE THIS AS TOOLTIP";
            }

        });

        TableViewerColumn lastnameColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableviewer, SWT.NONE);
        lastnameColumn.getColumn().setText("Nachname");
        lastnameColumn.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider(StyledCellLabelProvider.COLORS_ON_SELECTION) {

            @Override
            public void initialize(ColumnViewer viewer, ViewerColumn column) {
                super.initialize(viewer, column);
                this.setOwnerDrawEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                TestModel model = (TestModel) cell.getElement();
                cell.setText(model.getLastname());
                cell.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
            }

            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(Object element) {
                TestModel model = (TestModel) element;
                return "USE THIS AS TOOLTIP";
            }

        });

        for (TableColumn c : tableviewer.getTable().getColumns()) {
            c.pack();
        }

    }

    private void loadData() {

        entities = new ArrayList<TestModel>();

        entities.add(new TestModel("___Firstname1___", "Lastname1", "Username1", "Kommentar"));
        entities.add(new TestModel("___Firstname2___", "Lastname2", "Username2", "Kommentar"));
        entities.add(new TestModel("___Firstname3___", "Lastname3", "Username3", "Kommentar"));
        entities.add(new TestModel("___Firstname4___", "Lastname4", "Username4", "Kommentar"));
        entities.add(new TestModel("___Firstname5___", "Lastname5", "Username5", "Kommentar"));

        tableviewer.setInput(entities);
        tableviewer.refresh();

    }

}
```

And here are some faulty pictures

Here the native TableViewer Tooltip and my custom ToolTip is shown, also the row gets selected (COLORS_ON_SELECTION should prevent that)

[image: tooltip bug 1]

Here no tooltip is shown on the second column

[image: tooltip bug 2]

And here no tooltip is shown and as you can see the first cell isn't filled up

[image: tooltip bug 3]

If I add SWT.FULL_SELECTION the tooltip on column 2 appears but the other issues remain.

I think it's a kind of buggy that Tooltip Support or I am doing it totally wrong.

Comment: `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport` expects that you will override the label provider `getToolTipText` to provide the tooltip text.

Comment: ok thank you got it! But now a tooltip is shown on every column, not only if the text is larger than the column width. Is there any property I can check to suppress?

Comment: I provide the TableViewerColumn in the constructor and calculate the string width with an GC.stringExtent.x against the column.getColumn().getWidth()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28991593/1822033

The underlaying second tip was shown because the column was too narrow. Setting tableviewer.getTavle().setTooltipText(""); stopped showing the native tip.

Setting it to null displays it anyway!